# Strange behavior of Codeigniter session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am working on an application built on CodeIgniter. This application extends its controllers using a custom controller `CP_Controller` which lives in `application/core`. It looks like this:

```
class CP_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    var $settings;
    var $body_classes = array();
    var $data = array('theme' => 'cmodule');

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
        // print_r($_SESSION);
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is, `print_r($_SESSION);`. If I uncomment it, it prints `[__ci_last_regenerate] => 1589186369`. That's fine. No custom session data.

But for a particular request only, this returns a whole array filled up with session stuff. Even if it is the only request I run in a brand new browser session or private mode.

In this scenario, what's stranger is that business logic has not yet reached execution and no sessions have been set before this point. Then how's it possible that at this point, in a blank browser session, I am getting session data. I am not able to figure out the origin of this session data, where is it being set into the session? It only calls `parent::__construct();` before `print_r`.

Is there really any way a Codeigniter application can hook into session and populate a session at a very initial system bootstrap level (for that particular request only)? Or there could be any other way?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that session is started in very beginning. Have you tried running that request via Postman and deleting any cookies? How does that request looks like? Maybe you have some cached data that is later added to session?

Comment: (1) I tried on blank Chrome profile, no cookies, no luck. (2) It's a simple controller call like `index.php?d=a&c=b&m=c`. (3) There is no cache library in use, so I assume there's no cache